# Html helper Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to populate a dropdownlist and am getting a 500 error. CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

ViewModel:

```
public class InterestViewModel 
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> loanNames { get; set; }  
}
```

Controller:

```
using (var db = new db2rwEntities())
{
    model = new InterestViewModel();
    model.loanNames = db.PRODUCTs.Where(x =>    
            Constants.autoLoanTypes.Contains(x.FXP_TYPE_NBR ?? 0) && 
            x.PRODUCT_CLASS_CODE == 2
    ).Select(x => new SelectListItem() { 
        Text = x.PRODUCT_NAME, 
        Value = x.PRODUCT_NAME 
    }).ToList();
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("types", new SelectList(Model.loanNames, "Value", "Text"), new {multiple="multiple", data-placeholder="Select loan types" });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a data attribute rendered try:

`new { multiple = "multiple", data_placeholder = "Select loan types" }`

The underscore will be treated as a `-` when rendered, if I recall correctly.